# How can I run `$(nproc)`× parallel instances of `openssl dhparam` & when first instance exits with `0`, kill the other instances?

Tags: xargs, parallelism

I'm running `openssl dhparam -out dhparam4096.pem 4096` and it pegs a single core at 100% for the duration of the task (which can be considerable on some processors). I have 1 or more additional cores that are essentially idling, and I'd like to use them.

I'd like to run `$(nproc)`× instances of that command. The twist is that I don't need all the instances to complete – just the one that exits with `0` first…the remaining processes should be `SIGTERM`'d or similar as soon as the 'winner' instance is done, it need not be graceful.

I am learning `parallel` and `xargs` to achieve this, there are numerous how-to articles for completing *all* parallel tasks, but I'm falling short on the search engine fu to achieve the above. I'm not married to the idea of using `parallel` or `xargs`, I've got the [Parallel alternatives](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_alternatives.html) page in my reading list once I've found my way with it.

How can I run `$(nproc)`× instances of a command where the first instance to exit `0` will kill the other instances?

Other info: Debian 11, aarch64, `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the prompt of an interactive `zsh` shell:

```
(repeat $(nproc) { {your-command && kill 0} & }; wait)
```

Would run that subshell in a new process group, the first instance of `your-command` to exit successfully triggers a `kill 0` which kills that process group.

You can do the same with the `parallel` from `moreutils` with:

```
parallel sh -c 'your-command && kill 0' -- {1..$(nproc)}
```

(`{1..5}`, is from zsh and supported by many other shells nowadays even bash, but in bash you can't use an expansion in there, you can always replace with `$(seq "$(nproc)")` there assuming an unmodified `$IFS`).

Or with GNU `xargs`:

```
seq "$(nproc)" | xargs -P0 -n1 sh -c '
  your-command && kill 0'
```

Or explicitly binding each job to each CPU:

```
seq 0 "$(( $(nproc) - 1))" | xargs -P0 -ICPU taskset -c CPU sh -c '
  your-command && kill 0' sh-on-cpuCPU
```

The key each time is to run it at the prompt of an interactive shell so all the commands are put in a process group of their own.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fewer than 10000 cores:

```
seq 10000 | parallel -N0 --halt now,success=1 openssl dhparam -out dhparam4096.pem 4096
```